# Remove one character from a string at a time from right until a match is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have two temp tables populated with Id's.

The #Master table is from one system while the #Extended table is from another system where people have added characters to the Id.

The issue I'm now having is to write a `SELECT` query to check to see if there is a match or if not to remove one character at a time until there is a match. As you can see below there will be instances where there won't be an exact match in that case I would just like to return one of the possible values (1-12L7QABC could return 1-12L7QO or 1-12L7QM).

```
CREATE TABLE #Master(Id nvarchar(15), ClientName nvarchar(35));
INSERT INTO #Master
VALUES('1-12L7QO', 'John Citizen'),
      ('1-12L7QM', 'Steve Smith'), 
      ('1-10YL',   'Sarah Connor'), 
      ('1-2CN9WN', 'Cathy Rodgers');

CREATE TABLE #Extended(ExtId varchar(15));
INSERT INTO #Extended
VALUES('1-12L7QO`'), 
      ('1-12L7QABC'), 
      ('1-10YL'), 
      ('1-12L7QMTest');
```

The expected output is:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| Id            | BaseId        | Name                              |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1-12L7QO`     | 1-12L7QO      | John Citizen                      |
| 1-12L7QABC    | 1-12L7QO      | John Citizen                      |
| 1-10YL        | 1-10YL        | Sarah Connor                      |
| 1-12L7QMTest  | 1-12L7QM      | Steve Smith                       |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hint... use Extended.ID like Master.ID + '%' or some variant. Looping over each CHARINDEX isn't set based operations and thus is better handled with fuzzy matches and FULL TEXT indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to create all possible substrings and then do the match:

```
with m as (
      select m.id, m.ClientName
      from #Master m
      union all
      select left(m.id, len(m.Id) - 1), m.ClientName
      from m
      where m.Id <> ''
     )
select e.ExtId, m.Id, m.ClientName
from #Extended e outer apply
     (select top 1 m.*
      from m
      where e.ExtId like m.id + '%'
      order by len(m.id) desc
     ) m;
```

I don't want to argue that this is efficient, but it should do what you want.  And, it's fine on a small data set.

Comment: Very elegant solution and as the dataset I'm working on isn't that big plus is running as part of an ETL nightly, performance in this case is no issue. The only thing I wonder is that for the second line 1-12L7QABC could it display Steve Smith's full Id 1-12L7QM, instead of 1-12L7Q?

Comment: @sams . . . If you want the "full" id on the match, you can put that into the recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:Working exactly as you want.

```
            CREATE TABLE #MasterMatch(RowId INT,Master_Id nvarchar(15), ExtId varchar(15),ClientName nvarchar(35),Rank_Got Decimal(20,4));
            Select row_number() over(order by ExtId desc) as RowId,ExtId into #Extended1 from #Extended
            Declare @Id_Len INT
            Declare @Rec_Cnt INT
            Declare @ExtId varchar(15)
            Declare @ExtId1 varchar(15)
            SET @Rec_Cnt = (SELECT Count(1) FROM #Extended1)
            Print @Rec_Cnt
            WHILE(@Rec_Cnt > 0)
            BEGIN
            SELECT @ExtId = ExtId from #Extended1 where Rowid = @Rec_Cnt
            SET @ExtId1 = @ExtId
            SELECT @Id_Len = Len(@ExtId)
            WHILE (@Id_Len > 2)
            BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Master WHERE Id = @ExtId)
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #MasterMatch
            SELECT @Rec_Cnt,Id As Master_Id,@ExtId1 AS ExtId,ClientName,(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),@Id_Len)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),@Rec_Cnt)) As Rank_Got FROM #Master WHERE Id = @ExtId
            SET @Id_Len = (@Id_Len - 1)
            SET @ExtId = SUBSTRING(@ExtId,0,@Id_Len)
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO #MasterMatch
            SELECT @Rec_Cnt,Id As Master_Id,@ExtId1 AS ExtId,ClientName,(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),@Id_Len)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),@Rec_Cnt)) As Rank_Got FROM #Master WHERE Id like @ExtId + '%'
            SET @Id_Len = (@Id_Len - 1)
            SET @ExtId = SUBSTRING(@ExtId,0,@Id_Len)
            END
            END
            SET @Rec_Cnt = (@Rec_Cnt - 1)
            END

            Select Id,Base_id,Name 
            FROM (
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by ExtId ORDER BY Master_Id) As SnId,ExtId As Id,Master_Id As Base_id,ClientName As Name FROM #MasterMatch a INNER JOIN (select RowId,MAX(Rank_Got) As Rank_Got from #MasterMatch GROUP BY RowId) b on a.RowId = b.RowId and a.Rank_Got = b.Rank_Got
            ) one
            WHERE one.SnId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply unfortunately your solution for 1-12L7QO` returns Steve Smith, instead of John Citizen.